# What ABAP object has been changed today?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

Some functionality in a big project is broken on the development system.

Pretty sure it worked a few hours ago.

How do I know, which `ABAP` objects have been changed lately?
(I think I can guess the transport and the package that contains the change if that helps)

The nearest answer that I found is table `VRSD`.
It contains the date of the version of an object.
This doesn't help, since you need to export the transport or create a manual version to get an entry in this table.

So which objects have been changed without creating a new version?

(Yes we will find the change with functional checks, but knowing the changed objects would be a nice shortcut)

Comment: This is a good question. Unfortunately Change Management in SAP sucks as there is no Version Control System for it and such things are very hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

- For code - table TRDIR has a changed on date that updates when code is activated.
- For data dictionary objects check the DD* tables.  I know DD01L is domains and DD02L is tables.  Both of these will have a change date.  I'm sure there are others for the other data types.

Comment: One can activate the code even without changing it while it is active. I am pretty sure the date of the activation in the TRDIR changes in such a case even if there were no changes made to the code itself.

Comment: @Jagger: I just made a test and generated a report without a change. The field TRDIR-UDAT (Changed on) is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the table **REPOLOAD** which contains the ABAP byte code. There are 3 fields **UDAT, UTIME and UNAME** for date, time and user who did the last generation (PS: don't be confused by SDAT and STIME fields).